# How to match between multiple regex's and replace between them

Tags: javascript, regex

In any scientific paper given by user , program must.....

1. find :

1.a - The numeric citation e.g.

> Instead of reproducing full sentences from the summarized text, these
>   methods either compress the sentences **[1, 4-6]**, or re-generate new
>   sentences from scratch **[3]**.

1.b - The APA reference in the end of paper & just the authoe's name + year.

2. convert numeric to APA e.g.

> Instead of reproducing full sentences from the summarized text, these
>   methods either compress the sentences **(Jing 2000; Knight and Marcu
>   2000; Sporleder and Lapata 2005; Steinberger and Ježek 2006)**, or
>   re-generate new sentences from scratch **(McKeown et al 1999)**.

I figure the the regex to be :

```
"\[(\d.*?)\]"
```

for numeric citation.

```
"\d+([\.]([\ ])(([\D*])*([\,]))*([\ ][\w][\.]))|[\d]{4}"
```

for APA citation style.

My question is how to replace second pattern in the first pattern ?

Comment: How the heck is regex supposed to change `[1, 4-6]` to `(Jing 2000; Knight and Marcu 2000; Sporleder and Lapata 2005; Steinberger and Ježek 2006)`?!?

Comment: there will be References section in the paper like : 1.  Jing, H.: Sentence Reduction for Automatic Text Summarization. In Proceedings of the 6th Applied Natural Language Processing Conference, Seattle, USA, 2000, pp. 310–315. I can match the authors and the year. but how can i replace the number with strings i match

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "the APA reference in the end of paper"...

Comment: is this a homework assignment? Because the normal solution would be "someone has almost guaranteed already written this code, find that instead of reinventing the wheel".

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback function that splits the string of numbers (comma-delimited, potentially a range) into an array of numbers. Then loop through the numbers and use your other regex to look for the author/year. Then join these strings and return it for replacement.

```
var string = `Instead of reproducing full sentences from the summarized text, these methods either compress the sentences [1, 4-6], or re-generate new sentences from scratch [3].
1. Jing, H.: Sentence Reduction for Automatic Text Summarization. In Proceedings of the 6th Applied Natural Language Processing Conference, Seattle, USA, 2000, pp. 310–315.
3. McKeown et al: Sentence Reduction for Automatic Text Summarization. In Proceedings of the 6th Applied Natural Language Processing Conference, Seattle, USA, 1999, pp. 310–315.
4. Knight and Marcu.: Sentence Reduction for Automatic Text Summarization. In Proceedings of the 6th Applied Natural Language Processing Conference, Seattle, USA, 2000, pp. 310–315.
5. Sporleder and Lapata: Sentence Reduction for Automatic Text Summarization. In Proceedings of the 6th Applied Natural Language Processing Conference, Seattle, USA, 2005, pp. 310–315.
6. Steinberger and Ježek: Sentence Reduction for Automatic Text Summarization. In Proceedings of the 6th Applied Natural Language Processing Conference, Seattle, USA, 2006, pp. 310–315.`;

string.replace(/\[(\d[^\]]*)\]/g, function(matches, reference) {
    var numbers = [],
        authors = [];

    reference.split(/,\s*/g).forEach(function(number) {
        if(number.indexOf('-') !== -1) {
            var range = number.split('-');
            for(var i = range[0]; i <= range[1]; i++) {
                numbers.push(i);
            }
        } else numbers.push(number);
    });

    numbers.forEach(function(number) {
        var regex = new RegExp(number + '\\. ([^:]+):.*?(\\d{4})'),
            matches = regex.exec(string);
        authors.push(matches[1] + ' ' + matches[2]);
    });

    return '(' + authors.join('; ') + ')';
});
```